# is there any solution for $x^2 +x + 2 = e^x$ by using algebra?

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

I know this can be solved by numerical methods but I would like to know whether this can be solved using logs or something similar.

Thanks

Comment: It is not likely that the solution to this can be written down using only elementary functions.  Even the Lambert W function, which can solve many slightly simpler equations, does not seem to be applicable here because of the $x^2$ term.  That said, a unique inverse of the function $y = x^2+x-e^x$ *does* exist, at least when $y$ lies outside of a particular finite interval (inside this interval there are three admissible inverses).

Comment: are you asking if the real solution of the equation is also the root of a polynomial with rational coefficients?

Comment: If that was the question, the answer would be no: by Lindemann's theorem if $x$ is algebraic and nonzero, $e^x$ is transcendental.

Comment: @DavidHolden somewhat Yes; I mean having an algebraic expression for answer rather than numerical procedure; S.A.J gave all the points. it does not have an algebraic solution.

Comment: There is a series solution [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.01555.pdf) to $e^x=(x+a)(x+b)+c$

Answer (score -4, accepted):

No, such equations have not an algebraic answer.
However, you can solve this by using log.

just $Log_e$ both side, simplify and divide you'll have log(x^2+x+2) = x  etc it should be after that.
in addition, remember the log addition rules!

Comment: Takings logs simplifies the RHS but not the LHS. So while your first sentence is valid, the rest isn't.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I mentioned it has not an algebraic solution.

Comment: We can use this only to obtain an iterative numerical solution.

Comment: @S.A.J Got it, Thank you.